# woocommerce Products - Missing Product Id, Missing Brand name and Missing availability for google search console

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-search-console

i am are looking for solution to fix google search console Missing Product Id, Missing Brand name and Missing availability problem.

i visited the discussion https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22896 and found a solution https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22896#issuecomment-468435668

Right now  our site have some user reviews too that are shown as aggregate on google rich snippets. My question is : will above code remove reviews rating too from search console too. If yes then how can i avoid this.

version of woocomerce i am using is 3.5.7 and wordpress 5.1.1

or simply update to new woocommerce fix this ?